# How do I do a iPhone button-like fill

Tags: algorithm, delphi, graphics, fill

I'd like to spruce up some of the user controls I use and thought some attractive fills should do the job (part of it perhaps). Like the fill in the background of iPhone buttons or the Office 2007 ribbon bar (perhaps you know a few more).

**Edit:**
To clear things up, I don't need a simple gradient fill - there is a Windows API call for that. I am more interested in how the entire effect is achieved. Here is a [link to an article](http://www.keepthewebweird.com/iphone-style-icon-tutorial/) that shows how to do it in PhotoShop, but I want to accomplish that in code.

Specifically, the glossy gradient at the top ends in a curve roughly in the middle of the button. I half expect that this will need to be rendered separately and blended somehow.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're talking about the 3D effect of rounding or depth to a flat surface, it's called a gradient.

Comment: Are you talking about gradients? They are basically an interpolation (often linear) between two or more colors.

Comment: These are more complex than just a linear gradient. If you look at the IPhone for example, there is a gradient on the top half of the button but it is somewhat rounded at the bottom of the gradient and has lots of contrast with what is below. Here is a tutorial for doing it in PhotoShop, which is of course useless in my case:
http://www.keepthewebweird.com/iphone-style-icon-tutorial/

Now how do I do that in code?

Comment: FWIW: "fill algorithm" sounds like "flood fill algorithm", so the question, as worded, is a bit confusing. What you're actually asking for is just an arbitrary composition of some gradients. Maybe if you explain which part of it you're having trouble with you'll get a more helpful answer.

Comment: OK, I did say I didn't know exactly what to call it (still don't). And I'm asking for help precisely because the implementation is a total unkown. I'll edit the question to better reflect what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "glass" effect is made simply by creating a white ellipse around 4x larger than tall, placing it over the image to be "glassed" so that the bottom arc is centered on the image then alpha blending.  I believe this sample [delphi code](http://users.telenet.be/ws36637/transparent3.html) will be some help in performing the final portion.

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about gradient fills. You can get some code samples [here](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Graphics/Colors/index.html) to start with - search that page for "gradient" to find the relevant sections.

Answer (score 2):

You could try http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advsmoothbutton.asp. As far as I know this control is included in a free Smooth Controls pack with D2009. For other Delphi versions you could buy the TAdvSmoothButton control itself or as part of a control pack.

Comment: The smooth Controls are really great components : just try them.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is probably by assembling images based on the button size. Create a base image, and resize some layers over top of it, rather than trying to procedurally generating a complex gradient.

Comment: +1 I've found some examples and this seems to be the common way of doing it. I'm going to go with skamradt's answer though.